# MathJax in the Android App

Tags: bug, mathjax, android-app

Has anyone else noticed issues with MathJax in the StackExchange app? I'm aware the comments and titles don't render MathJax automatically, but I've also seen questions where certain math expressions lead to error messages in questions. The most recent and frequent example I see not rendering is `\dfrac` (for a recent example, see [MaxW's answer](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/68687/calculating-the-ph-of-the-endpoint-in-a-titration-of-weak-acid-and-strong-base/68703#68703) in the edit history).

**Edit**: To clarify, I'm seeing these errors for the Stack Exchange Android App Version 1.0.89

Comment: Indeed, there are a number of Mathjax commands that aren't rendered in the app. `\dfrac \tfrac \operatorname \lvert \rvert` come to mind, but I am sure there are more.

Comment: I have added the android app tag to your question. If you are using the iOS counterpart, you might want to add (and create) this tag, too. In general it would be nice if an iOS user could confirm this behaviour.

Comment: I'm also now seeing issues with "binom". (http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/71527/how-does-one-compute-the-number-of-unique-2-electron-integrals-for-a-given-basis)

Comment: I’ll note the existence of your problem, but please *do not* suggest edits that remove `\pu` from posts. The android app is just one of many ways to surf the site and I believe that browsers should still be the majority. You would be reducing benefit for the majority for a rather small minority.

Comment: @Jan I agree that the app is a smaller portion of the community, but I would argue if we can do things in a way that works both in the browser and in the app without unduly inconveniencing people, then why wouldn't we? Now maybe that wasn't the case with the particular post I edited, but I don't think it's a bad idea to have the app in mind in writing and editing posts. More ways to access SE will likely lead to more users and more active users. I think until the app is fixed, it's important to keep in mind that use of \pu when other options exist makes certain posts entirely unreadable.

Comment: Even `\pu` isn't rendered on the app.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately the app uses a different version than the website. That does include the recent updates to mhchem, especially the `\pu{...}` command.

While `\dfrac` can and should be avoided in general, that is not really true for the mhchem updates, as we would lose all the recent development discussed on meta.

We'll have to see and wait how the developers will continue their work on the app.

Comment: I hope they do it quickly, I'm getting sick of switching to browsers just to read the \pu thing. Besides, chat doesn't work on the app, and neither does per-site metas.

Comment: @PrittBalagopal I would not get my hopes up if I were you. There is a recent mother-meta post, which basically states that the development of the app is no priority at all. Too little traffic cones via the app, so improving the mobile pages is a larger concern...

Comment: I see. Do you recommend that I continue using the app or uninstall it and prefer the browser?

Comment: @PrittBalagopal that's something you need to figure out for yourself. I use the app mainly for chemistry-meta and the occasional question while I'm traveling. I don't find it too difficult to switch to the browser when necessary. The app has a limited functionality any way you look at it.